# How do I write a template that will be used on every page and then include sub-templates?

Tags: python, django, templates, themes

I followed the Django "first app" tutorial, and now I am wondering how I could write templates that the whole site will use. I can write the templates for each view, but how do I write a template that will be on every page and then include the 'sub templates' in say a 'content block'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Template Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) section of the Django template docs.

Basically, you create one template that is the "base":

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        {% block sidebar %}
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and save it as (for example) "base.html" in your template directory, then each specific page template looks like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}My amazing blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% for entry in blog_entries %}
    <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ entry.body }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: is it safe to include my templates from within each app's templates folder, given I'm using that proper loader? Or is it better to just use absolute paths?

Comment: @Addiction2Code I'm not sure I understand your question. You can put "base.html" wherever you want, so long as `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` and `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in `settings.py` allow you to find it, and then the specific page templates should be in app specific folders if you have multiple apps.

Comment: Also, take a look to {{ block.super }} that is really useful when working with template inheritance ;)

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you should write a base template and then extend this template. This is called template inheritance and is well explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)

Comment: SO answers should be useful without clicking through a link whenever possible, even if you basically just quote from the link like I did.

Comment: I had some doubts about the "validity" of my answer but then I thought it was ok as we actually answered at the same time, with almost the same answer; then you probably edited it. Next time I'll go for a comment if it's only for a link, thanks for advising.

Comment: Yeah, I often post "just the link" and then add context over the next couple of minutes. That way it's less likely five other people post the exact same thing while I'm trying to flesh out the details.